# Future of "User Instance" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

The following "SQL Server 2008 R2" page about "User Instances for Non-Administrators" has a note at the top that reads:

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx

What is the future of this feature? Will it be dropped entirely? Replaced by a different feature? Is SQL Server Compact edition meant to fill this space?

Bump. Nobody? Does anyone use the User Instance feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is deprecated in favor of SQL Server Compact 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

A few explanations on the reasoning from a Microsoft person: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/6764e959-4a32-49e3-ae84-61471d6a105a

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the links. I figured it was dropped in favor of CE but was unable to find an authoritative statement to that affect from Microsoft.

Comment: LocalDB in SQL Server Denail replaces "user instances", not SQL Server Compact

Comment: Why downvote? The question was about SQL Server 2008 R2, not Denali.