# How to specify a sql connection string on c# that will always work even if you change directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I have a connection string on a ASP.NET Solution...

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="F:\Prueba Documento Digital\Prueba Documento Digital\App_Data\BaseDeDatos.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

You may notice that it specifies an exact route because is located on mys USB Flash Drive, but what would happen if I move my solution to another place (Prueba Documento Digital is the name of the solution)?

I was trying something like ~/App_Data... but it didn't work...
What can be done?

Comment: .mdf files are SQL data files; meaning they need an SQL server to open it. I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's located on a USB drive. You can't just "move" an SQL Server. Maybe you should elaborate more on the environment you are running your solution (IIS?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDatos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the Database in the App_Data folder and access it via the DataDirectory

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDatos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

By default asp.net will check the App_Data folder when it sees the DataDirectory directive (except you change the DataDirectory by calling `AppDomain.SetData`)

Answer (score 1):

> it's simple, give server address, & in that access your data
>   directory & mention database filename. put your database file in `App_Data` folder

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|dataDirectory|\BaseDeDatos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True.
```

in this code, `AttachDbFilename` searches for database file named `BaseDeDatos.mdf`

Answer (score 1):

Just stop using the `AttachDbFileName` property and the [deprecated User Instance feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046044/future-of-user-instance-in-sql-server) in the first place. Do you really want to create a new copy of your database every time you start your application?

Instead, create your database directly on the actual Express instance, using [`CREATE DATABASE BaseDeDatos ... FOR ATTACH ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx). Then your application will always be referring to the proper copy of your database (I strongly recommend not moving your .mdf file around on a USB flash drive - if you want portable development, use Azure or something):

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BaseDeDatos;Integrated Security=True;
```